# Python : how to decode the text in s-language (strings)

Tags: python

Input exists out of a sentence or text in s-language: Isis thasat yousour sisisteser?

Output exists out same sentence without s-language : Is that your sister?

Problems:
I have the following code but some things are not working. For example I can not append after the if statements and my if statements are too litteral. Also the print(decoded_tekst) is not working.

Method:
I iterate through the different positions of the text with two variables ("vowelgroup" to store the vowels and "decoded text" to store the consonant and if "s" to replace it by the vowelgroup).

```
text = input('Enter a text: ')

vowelgroup = []  
decoded_text = [] 
sentence = [] 

vowel = 'aeiou'

count = 0

for i in text:
    if i is not vowel and not "s":
        sentence = decoded_text.append(i)
    if i is vowel:
        vowelgroup = vowelgroup.append(vowel)
    if i is "s":
        decoded_text = sentence.append(vowelgroup)
    count += 1
    print(decoded_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You look a little confused about how `append` works. `append` just adds the argument to the end of the list and it returns `None`. E.g:

```
l = [1,2]
a = l.append(3)
print a # None
print l # [1,2,3]
```

So you just use it like:

```
l = [1,2]
l.append(3)
print l # [1,2,3]
```